# How to get server's response on FileDrop.js jQuery interface?

Tags: jquery

I'm using http://filedropjs.org/#jquery to implement a file drop functionality to my web page.

The following is example code from the documentation:

```
$('<div><p>Drop something here...</p></div>')
  .appendTo(document.body)
  .filedrop()
  .on('fdsend', function (e, files) {
    // Occurs when FileDrop's 'send' event is initiated.
    $.each(files, function (i, file) {
      file.sendTo('upload.php')
   })
  })
  .on('filedone', function (e, file) {
    // Occurs when a File object has done uploading.
    alert('Done uploading ' + file.name + ' on ' + this.tagName)
  })
```

How can I read the server's response on 'filedone'? Object e or file don't seem to contain it (checked with JSON.stringify). I would like upload.php to rename and save the file and send the new file name back to the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this could be achieved just by adding xhr object to the 'filedone' function:

```
.on('filedone', function (e, file, xhr) {                                                
    var serverResponse = xhr.responseText;
}
```